# UseParallax ref hook not working with components in NextJs

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-ref

I'm trying to use the useParallax hook on an element in my js file. I'm using NextJs with ReactJs as well as styled components. I used the hook in the following way:

`Mainland.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import { useParallax } from 'react-scroll-parallax';

const Mainland = () => {
const { parallaxRef } = useParallax({ speed: 20 }); // set up the hook to use with useRef

const StyledDiv = styled.div`` //Styled Component

return (
<StyledDiv ref={parallaxRef}>
...
</StyledDiv>
```

*The error here is the following:*

> Error: You must assign the ref returned by the useParallax() hook to an HTML Element.

So I tried to use it without styled components and straight to an HTML element and it still didn't work.

**Extra Information:** I used the parallax provider in my _app.js file in the following way:

```
import Layout from '../Components/Layout';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { ParallaxProvider } from 'react-scroll-parallax';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, ...appProps }) {
  const isLayoutNeeded = [`/Contact`].includes(appProps.router.pathname);
  return (
    <>
      <Layout state={isLayoutNeeded}>
        <ParallaxProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ParallaxProvider>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

*Additional info:*
https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/usage/hooks/use-parallax

Answer (score 1):

The `useParallax` hook returns `{ ref, controller, element }`.

So try this:

```
const { ref: parallaxRef } = useParallax({ speed: 20 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Install module inside your project folder. That fixed it for me

```
npm i install react-scroll-parallax
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).